# Increase duration of Sudo

Tags: 14.04, sudo

I want to extend the duration of sudo in Ubuntu 14.04. It is irritating to provide password repeatedly. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu default `sudo` session is `15` minute (may change with different version) but you can change it . Run and open

```
sudo visudo
```

and change line :

```
Defaults    env_reset
```

to

```
Defaults   env_reset,timestamp_timeout=20
```

It will not ask for `20` minute. if you do `0` then it will ask every time and 
if `-1` then it will never prompt for password for `sudo` session.