# Increase sudo timeout from within a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sudo

I have a bash script that installs a lot of software. The whole process takes around 1h therefore I would like to increase the `sudo` timeout variable. I see it is possible as described here: [Increase duration of Sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688582/increase-duration-of-sudo).

However, I cannot find a description for the command line anywhere...
In my case I would like to make this change from within the script. I could put something like: `sudo echo 'Defaults    timestamp_timeout=300' >> /etc/sudoers` at the first line within the bash script. This, however, is not allowed.

Comment: It's usually simpler to remove any `sudo`s from *inside* the script, and run the whole script with `sudo`

Comment: BTW here's why your attempt to modify the sudoers file failed: [How to solve “permission denied” when using sudo with redirection in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/how-to-solve-permission-denied-when-using-sudo-with-redirection-in-bash) (I don't recommend doing that though)

Comment: @steeldriver : I cannot run the whole script as sudo, it contains commands which specifically cannot be run with root privileges

Comment: So how about dropping privileges for those specific commands (using `sudo -u` for example)?

Comment: This would require the users to be known to the bash from inside the script? This is not the case...

Comment: ... `$SUDO_USER` doesn't work for some reason?

Comment: @steeldriver: I just tested that, it works, it correctly returns my name from inside the script. But now I have a problem that when the script calls `sudo -u $SUDO_USER cp DIR/file file` (being inside `$HOME`) . I get `cp failed to access 'file': Permission denied`. Is it possible to operate on `$HOME` as non-root while the script was called with `sudo`?

Comment: OK, I have solved it, it was because `$HOME` points to a different place whether calling the script with/without `sudo`. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I will post an answer to my problem in case anyone else runs into such issue in the future.
Thanks for the help @steeldriver.

Indeed, it is better to use `sudo` on the whole script and then escape commands within which specifically need to be run as the user with a prefix: `sudo -u $SUDO_USER`. Importantly, when the script is run with root privileges the `$HOME` changes, so be careful. In order to refer to the original user's home create a variable:

`USER_HOME=$(sudo -u $SUDO_USER -H -s eval 'echo $HOME')`

and then operate on paths with the prefix of `$USER_HOME`, if required.